# How to create a ASP.NET 5 project in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013

I was trying to create a asp.net 5 project in Visual Studio 2013. What are the extensions I need to download to make it run in Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: I don't think you can do this.

Comment: So then it is only supported in Visual Studio 2015?

Comment: I would download Visual Studio Code and go from there

Answer (score 0):

in your project using Nuget Package Manager console run this

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc -Version 5.2.3
```

More information on [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc/5.2.3) this is if you are talking about MVC 5, 
but if you need ASP.NET 5 information and download [available here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/introducing-asp-net-5)